# PHP detecting if a function has an optional argument

Tags: php

Suppose I have this class:

```
class Test
{
    public function foo($argument = "") {
        //do something
    }

    public function bar($argument) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can tell if foo's argument is optional, and bar's argument isn't through PHP?

I've tried using getParameters() from ReflectionMethod, but that just returns the name, and not any information that can tell me if it is optional or not.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.isoptional.php

Comment: @SvenB How wouldn't it work? `getParameters` returns an array of `ReflectionParameter` objects. Loop over them, call `->isOptional`, get the info you need. Show us some code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

With reflected methods [`getParameters`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php) will return an array of [`ReflectionParameter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionparameter.php)s. You can check the `isOptional` method on `ReflectionParameter`.

When you echo or print a `ReflectionParameter` it will return its name.

Here's [an example](https://ideone.com/urmLY5)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by detecting if function has optional argument.

But whats wrong with doing this ?

```
public function foo($argument = "") {
    if($argument != "") {
       .... argument is set
    }
}
```

Edit: I see what you mean now. Yes you can use reflections for that

```
$reflection = new ReflectionMethod($className, $methodName);
$params = $reflection->getParameters();
foreach ($params as $param) {
    echo $param->getName();
    echo $param->isOptional();
}
```

Comment: I'm testing if it has an optional argument from another class.

Comment: @Starfire1337 Ah i see what you mean yes you can use reflections for that